# How can I find out through java where jboss is going to put my server logs?

Tags: java, jboss, logging

Is there a way I can detect where jboss is writing the console log file?

I am using java.util.logger and log4j.

Comment: @OndraŽižka Unfortunately we're at version 4.2.3 and can't upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if there's a system property called `jboss.server.log.dir`. You should be able to read this value with `System.getProperty("jboss.server.log.dir")`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I couldn't find this for the life of me while googling it... http://learnertobeginner.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-set-jbossserverlogdir-in-jboss.html

Comment: Speaking of that, [all system properties available within JBoss AS 7 JVM are in the boot.log](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7BootLogContent). Check the link for an example.

Answer (score 0):

If it's AS 7, you can add the logging module as your module's dependency and reach the logging service, which will have this info.
Also, you might get that info through the Management API.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Management+API+reference

Unfortunately what you need is still empty:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/The+native+management+API